# Prevent screen rotation in a PWA if it is locked in the OS

Tags: android, google-chrome, rotation, progressive-web-apps, web-manifest

When I try to open my PWA on an Android device, the screen rotates even though screen rotation is locked in the OS. I tried to open on Realme 6 (Android 11) and Huawei (Android 10).

How to prevent screen rotation if it is locked in the OS?

Comment: please consider mark the answer as correct to help others. thnks!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove orientation from the manifest.json, so it uses the default system orientation.

https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dfn-default-screen-orientation

Comment: Ive been searching this for 2 months!!! call me a noob but is it possible that this HUGE HACK isnt decribed anywhere in MDN o WEBDEV or googling a lot?!?!! THANKS A LOT FRIEND!!